# How to get just upper value based on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table test which has ticket and vehcile.

```
ticket  vehicle
1000    101
1001    102
1002    102
1003    103
1004    104
1005    102
1006    102
```

My requirement: Input will be ticket and ouput will be vehicle.If the vehcile is repeating then I have to get just the previous ticket.

**For example:** ticket 1006 has vehicle 102 which is repeating.I mean 1006,1005,1002,1001 tickets have vehicle 102.So if the input is 1006 then output will be 1005. Similarly if the input is 1005,output will be 1002.And if the input is 1002 then output will be 1001.
I did like this

```
SELECT ticket
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ticket desc) AS RowNumber, *
      FROM test
      WHERE vehicle = (SELECT vehicle FROM test WHERE ticket = 1005)) AS getsecondsLast
WHERE RowNumber = 2
```

but this only works properly if the input is 1006.

Please help me [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca9cd/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca9cd/19)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table test(
  ticket int,vehicle int);
  insert into test values(1000,101);
  insert into test values(1001,102);
  insert into test values(1002,102);
  insert into test values(1003,103);
  insert into test values(1004,104);
    insert into test values(1005,102);
  insert into test values(1006,102);
```

**Query 1**:

```
declare @ticket int = 1005;

select top(1) T1.ticket
from dbo.test as T1
where T1.ticket < @ticket and
      T1.vehicle in (
                    select T2.vehicle
                    from dbo.test as T2
                    where T2.ticket = @ticket
                    )
order by T1.ticket desc;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca9cd/19/0)**:

```
| ticket |
|--------|
|   1002 |
```

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca9cd/22

```
DECLARE @ticket int = 1006

select MAX(prev.ticket) from test curr
inner join test prev
on curr.vehicle = prev.vehicle
  AND curr.ticket > prev.ticket
where curr.ticket = @ticket
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is the simplest way to do it (if the vehicle has only one ticket then return null as the ticket number)

```
DECLARE @ticket int = 1006

SELECT TOP 1 t2.ticket, t1.vehicle
FROM test t1 LEFT JOIN test t2 ON(t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle AND t2.ticket < t1.ticket)
WHERE t1.ticket = @ticket
ORDER BY t2.Ticket DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

This will return the original ticket if the `Vehicle` is not repeating.

```
DECLARE @ticket INT = 1002

;WITH CteUnion AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM Test
    WHERE
        Ticket = @ticket
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM Test
    WHERE
        Vehicle = (SELECT Vehicle FROM Test WHERE Ticket = @ticket)
        AND Ticket < @ticket

),
CteNumbered AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN =
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                ORDER BY 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN Ticket = @ticket THEN -1
                        ELSE Ticket
                    END
                DESC
            )
    FROM CteUnion
)
SELECT Ticket, Vehicle
FROM CteNumbered
WHERE RN = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ec25c/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

This way you get answer as you want.

take a look at this **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca9cd/53/0)**

**Query:**

```
Select ticket, vehicle, (Case When Output IS NULL Then ticket else Output End) As PrevTicket
from test t1
outer apply (select max(ticket) as Output from test t2 
where t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle and t2.ticket < t1.ticket) t3
```

Here you can add `Where` condition to get output for particular ticket.

```
Where ticket = 1005
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Select *
from test outer_test
outer apply 
(select max(ticket) as Previous_Ticket from 
 test inner_test 
 where inner_test.vehicle = outer_test.vehicle
 and outer_test.ticket > inner_test.ticket) previous
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ca9cd/69/0

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the fiddle does not show anything